# Udev won't execute some lines in my script

Tags: bash, debian, script, udev, beaglebone

I'm working on a Beaglebone Black under debian.
I'm writing Udev rules to manage µSD card.
What i need Udev to do: when my µSD is plugged in, Mount the µSD on `/media/sdcard` (it does) and execute the script that does:

- Stop rsyslog.service (it does)
- Move /var/log to /media/sdcard (it does NOT)
- create a link from /var/log to /media/sdcard/log (to continue logging but in the SDcard) (it does NOT but the /media/sdcard/log does not exist because the precedent step has failed)
- restart rsyslog service (it does)

Here is the script that does what i just described:

```
logger 'Enterring /root/ServolineScripts/LogsonSDcard.sh script'
logger 'Refreshing Mountinglogs'
sudo rm /var/log/Mountinglogs.log
logger 'Stopping syslog service'
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog stop
sudo mv /var/log /media/sdcard/
sudo ln -s /media/sdcard/log /var/log
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog start
logger 'Successfully restarted rsyslog, logs are back on syslog!'
logger 'Restarted syslog service'
logger 'Quitting /root/ServolineScripts/LogsonSDcard.sh script'
```

I'm not sure why it does not move the /var/log directory. 
This same script executed by hand with a simple sh /root/ServolineScripts/LogsonSDcard.sh works...

I wonder if it is a problem of rights...

Comment: Gosh, why there are much `sudo` calls? `udev` runs its scripts with root permissions, it does not need no `sudo`. And `sudo` may easily not do what you supposedly expect it to in the general case. I mean, please stop mindlessly replicating whatever crap you see in random blog posts; put a hefty amount of thought in what you implement.

Comment: OK, I digress. Now to your real problem. If you remove all those `sudo` prefixes, does it work? Another possible approach is to have a wrapper script which would run another one — containing only the "action" statements and no calls to logger and pipe both its output streams to the `logger` (which is able to consume input on its stdout). Something like `script_which_does_stuff 2>&1 | logger -t microsd`

Comment: you're right with the overusage of sudo ;) I did not reflect that Udev was executing as root... (stupid boy!) OK i already had the idea to do an actions script and i was wondering why it should work... but i'm on it!
Thanks! i'll be back when it will work (i hope...)

Comment: i'm back and it works much better without the sudo! ;)
And with two seperate scripts. @kostix do you have an explanation on why it works with two different scripts and not with one?

Comment: I don't. But I think that leaving out `sudo` could be the sole reason it works ;-)

Comment: i just have one more strange thing... i did a copy and paste in different functions that i call in my main script but when the script creates the link from /var/log to /media/sdcard/log the result is a link in /media/sdcard/log to /media/sdcard/log... very strange because executed by hand the first script i wrote in my post was working perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write an answer with what helped me in the comments.

Credits to @kostix ;)

---

The main problem was probably the **overusage of sudo** in a script that is executed by **Udev which already have root permissions**.
@kostix proposed me to **write two different scripts**, one with the actions and one main that calls the functions in the actions script.
I did both of the solution, deleting the `sudo` that don't need to exist and creating an other script with actions. It worked perfectly and i'm now able to look on other problems in my script!